# How to increase every element in a vector by a specified value?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a generic function that will increase every element in a container by a specified value, but I am getting random values outputted to the screen instead. I am assuming it's the memory address that is getting outputted, I am just not sure how to get it to work properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code below.

```
template<class iterator, class T>
T increment(iterator start, iterator stop, const T & x)
{
    for (iterator itr = start; itr != stop; ++itr)
    {
        itr + x;
    }
}


int main() {

vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

cout << increment(v.begin(), v.end(), 5);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: As state in doc [iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) : *The most obvious form of iterator is a pointer*. You need to dereference by using `*` to access the value, and you should to `*itr += x;`

Comment: Your `increment` does not return anything, yet you try to print it's return value. Please do yourself a favour and use your compilers warning options to their full (`-pedantic` may do in this case).

Comment: Or directly in `main`: `for (auto& e : v) { e += 5;}`. :)

Comment: The function `increment` should return a `T` value otherwise the return value is undefined.

Comment: Side-note: This operation is directly demonstrated in [cppreference's `std::for_each` docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each). Your specific case can simplify to just: `std::for_each(start, stop, [&x](T& n){ n += x; });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a function that returns a value other than void and other than main function should return it correctly otherwise if the function fails to provide a valid return value then the result is undefined.

You can change your function `increment` to look like:

```
template<typename T>
void increment(std::vector<T>& vec, T val) {
    for (auto& e : vec)
        e += val;
}


int main(){

    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for (const auto& i : v)
        std::cout << i << ", "; 
    std::cout << std::endl; 

    increment(v, 5);

    for (const auto& i : v)
        std::cout << i << ", ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```